Firefox refuses to visit a single website in my home network, 192.168.1.232: NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I have an unraid server running locally at 192.168.1.232. On my mac laptop and windows desktop, while on my home's wifi, I can visit a bunch of services and webapps, like immich, sonarr, unraid's dashboard, etc, by visiting 192.168.1.232:8888 for example. This works on every browser and every computer in my home network except for firefox on this single mac laptop.
When I try to visit http://192.168.1.232:8888 on this macbook using Firefox, I get the following error in the screen:

Unable to connect
An error occurred during a connection to 192.168.1.232.

The network tab says: NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with no other details.
Some other notes:

There's no entry in /etc/hosts for this IP
visiting other machines in my network, such as my router at 192.168.1.254, works fine.
visiting the server using chrome or safari on this same laptop works fine.
I've disabled extension, run in private browsing, tried troubleshooting mode, and even reinstalled firefox fresh. (But maybe there's a setting or cached file somewhere that remained after uninstalling it.)
Firefox can visit this server on other computers fine.
if I visit using my cloudflare URL, firefox works fine.
The services on that server are all working.
This only started a couple weeks ago; previously there was no problem. I don't know what changed, but I know it was around the time I was messing with cloudflare and dns stuff to get some URLs set up with cloudflare-d.

It's just

firefox (v133.0.3)
on this laptop (Mac OS Sequoia 15.2)
visiting any service/port on this IP (192.168.1.232)

Can you help? Any other thoughts or suggestions? Is there a better way to clean firefox's installation? Or maybe downgrade to an earlier version of firefox?

Have you tried another browser. e.g., Chrome-based Brave? Have you trried setting up an additional Firefox profile, to see if the existing one is damaged: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles ?

I've only tested with chrome and safari, but the internal websites at the IP work on those browsers. I'll try with a new profile and see.

Maybe you previously ran a service on :8888 that set HSTS and now Firefox won't let you connect to the service that's there now because the new service is not offering TLS. See if you can figure out how to clear Firefox's HSTS site list.

@Spiff I removed everything in the profile folder, including the HSTS file. No success. Thanks for the suggestion.
